# Printing out function containing print and return

Tags: python, printing, return

I recently came across a weird problem.
I assumed that the two code snippets below should have the same output, yet they do not. Can someone explain?

```
def my_function():
    myvar = "a"
    print("2", myvar)
    return myvar
```

1. 

```
print("1")
print(my_function())

#will output:
#1
#2 a
#a
```

2. 

```
print("1", my_function())

#will output:
#2 a
#1 a
```

I assumed that in the second example the "1" should be printed before the function is invoked and their internal print statement is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function with parameters, the parameters have to be fully evaluated before calling the function.

In the case of `2.` python effectively rewrites your code like this:

```py
_ = my_function()
print("1", _)
```

So `my_function()` is called first, then the parameters are passed to `print()`

Comment: Thx awesome. That answered it :)